# Unauthenticate a user based on some action happend in cloud function?

Tags: firebase-authentication

Is there a way to trigger unauth action based on a user id inside a cloud function ?

I am trying to sign a user out my app if some criteria met inside one onRequest cloud function.

Is this possible ?

Sure I can deploy some listeners on client side but I need fool proof way to force re auth the users due a major change is his custom claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication is based on a combination of a long-lived refresh token and ID tokens, that are valid for an hours after they are minted. While it is possible to [revoke the user's refresh token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens), there is no way to revoke such an ID token once it is minted.

The common approach is to track revoked tokens yourself somewhere, and then check in your client and server side code whether the user is using a revoked token. For more on this, see the documentation on [detecting revoked ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation).

Comment: In my implementation I am using the vanilla firebase auth no JSWT so I was wondering if some one can change a custom claim in a cloud function why then cannot nullify the auth rendering the target user unauthorized which in this case can let me implement some logic in my onAuthchange in client .